# Scrapy getting href out of div

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I started to use Scrapy for a small project and I fail to extract the link. Instead of the url I get only "[]" for each time the class is found. Am I missing something obvious?

```
sel = Selector(response)
for entry in sel.xpath("//div[@class='recipe-description']"):
    print entry.xpath('href').extract()
```

Sample from the website:

```
<div class="recipe-description">
    <a href="http://www.url.com/">
        <h2 class="rows-2"><span>SomeText</span></h2>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your xpath query is wrong. You must select the link and then get the href attribute. Something like this: //a[@href]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

your xpath query is wrong

```
for entry in sel.xpath("//div[@class='recipe-description']"):
```

in this line you are actually iterating our divs that doesn't have any Href attribute

for making it correct you should select `achor` elements in `div`:

```
for entry in sel.xpath("//div[@class='recipe-description']/a"):
    print entry.xpath('href').extract()
```

best possible solution is extract `href` attribute in `for` loop directly

```
for href in sel.xpath("//div[@class='recipe-description']/a/@href").extract():
    print href
```

for simplicity you can also use css selectors

```
for href in sel.css("div.recipe-description a::attr(href)").extract():
    print href
```