# Using Scrapy to get Next Link

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having difficulty getting Scrapy to recognize a next page link. If you use xpath //a the link does not show up. And I tried

```
response.xpath("//*[@id='nextpage']/a").extract()
```

with no luck along with multiple other permutations. I am trying to parse the `href="pdetail.php?instnum=2016230702&amp;year=2016"` link

Here is the code:

```html
<div class=""><br>
<table width="95%" align="center">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td align="center" class="">
            <h3 style="" class="Header">
                Detail Information For Instrument # 2016230701 In Year 2016            </h3>
        </td>

        <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td class=""><div style="float:left;margin-left:30px;" id="previouspage" class=""><a href="pdetail.php?instnum=2016230700&amp;year=2016"><button style="font-size:18px;font-family: arial" type="button" class="">Previous Page</button></a> </div></td>
    <td class=""></td>
    <td class=""><div style="float:right;" id="nextpage" class=""><a href="pdetail.php?instnum=2016230702&amp;year=2016"><button style="font-size:18px;font-family: arial" type="button" class="">Next Page</button></a></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I run permutation of the xpath and I get the following loop - with the page calling back on itself:

```
2016-09-24 18:26:03 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://search.jeffersondeeds.com/pdetail.php?instnum=2016230701&year=2016&db=0&cnum=20> (referer: http://search.jeffersondeeds.com/pdetail.php?instnum=2016230701&year=2016&db=0&cnum=20)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281413/scrapy-getting-href-out-of-div You may want to visit w3school's xpath tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this *xpath* :

```
string(//*[@id="nextpage"]/a/@href)
```

Comment: In my script it pulls up the current URL and loops. In the scrapy shell nothing shows up though. This is what I see on the command line: 2016-09-24 17:57:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://search.jeffersondeeds.com/pdetail.php?instnum=2016230701&year=2016&db=0&cnum=20> (referer: http://search.jeffersondeeds.com/pdetail.php?instnum=2016230701&year=2016&db=0&cnum=20)

Comment: Maybe try to click the button right after the `a` link

Comment: thanks Gilles - That was the correct xpath according to my xpath helper extension. Now I just need my script to recognize it!