# How do I crawl a page to the href elements using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a page and print the `hrefs`, however I am not getting any response. Here is the spider -

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class Shoes2Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name            = "shoes2"
    allowed_domains = ["stockx.com"]
    start_urls      = ["https://www.stockx.com/sneakers"]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = "//div[@class='css-pnc6ci']/a"), 
            callback                      = "parse_item", 
            follow                        = True
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Also here is an example of the `hrefs` I'm trying to extract -
[image]

When I run the spider, I'm expecting to see 40 `hrefs`, however I'm getting nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Also here is code to create the project in terminal -

```bash
scrapy startproject stockx

cd stockx

scrapy genspider -t crawl shoes2 www.stockx.com/sneakers
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36281413) answer your question?

Comment: @grimsteel Not quite. That is one way to do it, however I am trying to to this by setting rules in the scrapy crawler.

Answer (score 0):

So I just realized that the `start_urls` was set to `["https://www.stockx.com"]`. I changed this to `["https://www.stockx.com/sneakers"]` and that appears to have fixed the issue.

Comment: what version of scrapy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class Shoes2Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "shoes2"
    allowed_domains = ["stockx.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.stockx.com/sneakers"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='[data-testid="RouterSwitcherLink"]'), callback="parse_item", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

This is will work. I have updated CSS `restrict_css='[data-testid="RouterSwitcherLink"]'`